# can't uninstall netbeans in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall

I am using netbeans8.0 new version, I want to uninstall lower version netbeans7.4 I tried using the following command in my `terminal`:

> root@selvaksa-OEM:/usr/local/netbeans-7.4# sh uninstall.sh

while executing this I get the following error:

```
Specified target component -nb-base/7.4.0.0.201310111528 
was not found in the registry. the Installer 
can continue as if the target component was not specified.
Click yes to continue, no to exit
```

if I click `yes`, it is asking to `uninstall` and then click `uninstall` to continue it is showing click `finish` to finish the IDE setup.

> netbeans7.4 IDE

Comment: @Anthon all are making the correction, but no one helps to solve the solution(answer)...

Comment: that is probably because people ignore question that have spelling mistakes. This is still not a real question, as there is no sentence with a question mark in sight. Any reason not to install/uninstall netbeans using `apt-get`?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it with:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/netbeans
rm -rf /usr/local/glassfish
rm -rf /root/.nbi
```